# Print string as HTML

Tags: python, html, newline, genshi

I would like to know if is there any way to convert a plain unicode string to HTML in Genshi, so, for example, it renders newlines as `<br/>`.

I want this to render some text entered in a textarea.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If Genshi works just as KID (which it should), then all you have to do is

```
${XML("&lt;p&gt;Hi!&lt;/p&gt;")}
```

We have a small function to transform from a wiki format to HTML

```
def wikiFormat(text):
    patternBold = re.compile("(''')(.+?)(''')")
    patternItalic = re.compile("('')(.+?)('')")
    patternBoldItalic = re.compile("(''''')(.+?)(''''')")
    translatedText = (text or "").replace("\n", "<br/>")
    translatedText = patternBoldItalic.sub(r'<b><i>\2</i></b>', textoTraducido or '')
    translatedText = patternBold.sub(r'<b>\2</b>', translatedText or '')
    translatedText = patternItalic.sub(r'<i>\2</i>', translatedText or '')
    return translatedText
```

You should adapt it to your needs.

```
${XML(wikiFormat(text))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert plain text to HTML, by escaping "`<`" and "`&`" characters (and maybe some more, but these two are the absolute minimum) as HTML entities
2. Substitute every newline with the text "`<br />`", possibly still combined with a newline.

In that order.

All in all that shouldn't be more than a few lines of Python code. (I don't do Python but any Python programmer should be able to do that, easily.)

**edit** I found [code on the web](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml) for the first step. For step 2, see `string.replace` at the bottom of [this page](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, this is how I solved it. This is the python code before the data is sent to the genshi template.

```
from trac.wiki.formatter import format_to_html
from trac.mimeview.api import Context
...
    context = Context.from_request(req, 'resource')
    data['comment'] = format_to_html(self.env, context, comment, True)
    return template, data, None
```

Comment: Forget to say this runs on Trac.